# Missing item error with xsim and TeXLive 2020

Tags: enumitem, exercises, xsim, texlive-2020

I recently updated from TeXLive 2019 to TeXLive 2020. After upgrading the code from [this](https://texwelt.de/fragen/23968/xsim-ubung-losung-zusatzlich-kurzlosung) link (only slightly modified) didn't work anymore. It terminates with the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

The full mwe:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = default,
  exercise/name = Aufgabe,
  solution/name = Lösung,
}

% from https://texwelt.de/fragen/23968/xsim-ubung-losung-zusatzlich-kurzlosung
\DeclareExerciseProperty{shortsolution}
\newcommand\printshortsolutions{%
  \begin{description}[leftmargin=3cm, style=sameline]
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
      \def\ExerciseType{##1}%
      \def\ExerciseID{##2}%
      \GetExercisePropertyT{shortsolution}%
        {%
          \item[Kurzlösung ##3] ####1%
        }%
    }%
  \end{description}
}
\NewEnviron{shortsolution}{\SetExpandedExerciseProperty{shortsolution}{\expandonce{\BODY}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
  This is the exercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{shortsolution}
  This is the shortsolution
\end{shortsolution}
\begin{solution}
  The Solution
\end{solution}

% works only without this line
\printshortsolutions

\printallsolutions
\end{document}
```

I assume that there must have been changes to the syntax of the `xsim` commands but I was not able to spot them in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with version 0.19 (2020/03/16) ox `xsim` both `\ExerciseType` and `\ExerciseID` are only set locally in order to allow nesting of different exercise types. As a consequence `\Set(Expanded)ExerciseProperty` can't be used outside of an exercise any more. The solution is to move

```
\begin{shortsolution}
  This is the shortsolution
\end{shortsolution}
```

inside the exercise.

The following code demonstrates this and also gets rid of the `environ` – it is not necessary any more.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = default,
  exercise/name = Aufgabe,
  solution/name = Lösung,
}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{shortsolution}

\newcommand*\printshortsolutions{%
  \begin{description}[leftmargin=3cm, style=sameline]
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
      \def\ExerciseType{##1}%
      \def\ExerciseID{##2}%
      \GetExercisePropertyT{shortsolution}%
        {%
          \item[Kurzlösung ##3] ####1%
        }%
    }%
  \end{description}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{shortsolution}{b}
  {\SetExpandedExerciseProperty{shortsolution}{#1}}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  This is the exercise
  \begin{shortsolution}
    This is the shortsolution
  \end{shortsolution}
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  The Solution
\end{solution}

\printshortsolutions

\printallsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That must have been the fastest answer I've ever got on TeX.SE!

Comment: I hope there will be a major revision to the documentation?

Comment: @Davislor I don't think that anywhere in the is mentioned that setting properties outside of the exercise would work so I'm not sure why a major revision should be necessary.

Comment: @cgnieder Maybe the legacy code only ever worked by accident, but it’s still a change that breaks legacy code, and other people might have the same problem.

Comment: @cgnieder So, major revision or not, it seems worth a prominent note.

Comment: @Davislor OK,fair enough. The manual says in the first section in a red highlighted box “Please also be aware that xsim is actively developed and many things may still change.” because xsim is still in an unstable development state. I'll address this more explicitly in the next release.

Comment: @cgnieder Okay.